# Is $ h(x)= \begin{cases} x[\frac{1}{x}] & \text{if } x \neq 0, \\ 1 & \text{if } x=0. \\ \end{cases} $ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, graphing-functions

> Draw the graph and study the discontinuity points of the function
>
> $$
> h(x)= \begin{cases}
> x[\frac{1}{x}]    & \text{if } x \neq 0, \\
>  1 & \text{if } x=0. \\
> \end{cases}
> $$

Where $[\frac{1}{x}]$ is the floor of $\frac{1}{x}$.

My attempt:

[image]

- The limit doesn’t exist at $x=1$

$\lim_{x \to 1^+} h(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to 1^-} h(x)=1 $

Thus, $h$ is not continuous at $x=1$

- $\lim_{x\to 0^+} h(x)=\ lim_{x\to 0^-} h(x)=h(0)=1 $

Hence, $h$ is continuous at $x=0$.

The function is continuous on $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$. Is that true?

Edit:

I noted that

- If $\frac{1}{2}<x\le 1$ then $x[\frac{1}{x}]=x$
- If $\frac{1}{3}<x\le \frac{1}{2}$ then $x[\frac{1}{x}]=2x$
- If $\frac{1}{4} < x \le \frac{1}{3}$ then $x[\frac{1}{x}]=3x$

.

.

- If $\frac{1}{n+1} < x \le \frac{1}{n}$, then $x[\frac{1}{x}]=nx$

And we have that

$\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{2}^-} f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{2}^+} f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$

Then the limit does not exit at $x=\frac{1}{2}$

$\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{3}^-} f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{3}^+} f(x)=\frac{2}{3}$

Then the limit does not exit at $x=\frac{1}{3}$.

In general, $\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{n}^-}=1\neq \lim_{x \to \frac{1}{n}^+}=\frac{n-1}{n}$

Then, $f$ is not continuous at $x=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: Plotting this on (say) Desmos reveals the graph to be quite different from what you depict on the interval $(-1, 1)$, as Torsten suggests.  You should be very cognizant of what happens at $x = \frac1k\pm\varepsilon$, for various integers $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that between $-1$ and $1$ the function looks as you claim it does. E.g. for irrational $x \in (0,1)$, $h(x)$ will be irrational.

Of course the points where discontinuities *can* occur are exactly the ones where $\lfloor 1/x\rfloor$ is discontinuous. Which are they? And which of them really give discontinuities? (I think most of them do.)

Finally, I think that your one-sided limits at $x=0$ are correct, but you don't give arguments for them. As a hint, one can e.g. use $1/x-1 \le \lfloor 1/x\rfloor \le 1/x$.

Comment: I edit my post, can you see it please?

Comment: Your new argument for $x \in (0,1]$ and in particular $x=1/n$ looks perfect to me. Just also look at $x \in [-1, 0)$ and in particular $x=-1/n$ .

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if ts correct but i think like this.
f(X) = x[1/x],
check at $x->0^-$ it will be $->0*$(some constant)=0...(as gif will yield some unknown but 'fixed' constant
similarly for the rhl it will again be $->0*$(some different constant)=0.
lhl=rhl but not eqaul to f(x) so it contains removable discontinuity so function is discontinous