# Limit of a floor function.

Tags: limits

The following limit evaluates to $1$.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]$  , where [ ] is the floor function.

I still think that the left hand limit diverges to negative infinity while the right hand limit diverges to positive infinity.

Comment: What do you mean by left and right hand, in this case?

Comment: By left l mean when lim h --> 0 ( 0-h) and by right hand limit l mean when h-->0 ( 0+h) . Is there a way of solving it without using sqeeuze theorem.

Comment: Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3127897/96384.

Comment: Yes and thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $$x-1<\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$$

So $$\frac{1}{x}-1<\bigg\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \bigg\rfloor \leq \frac{1}{x}$$

$$x\bigg(\frac{1}{x}-1\bigg)<x\bigg\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \bigg\rfloor\leq x\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg)$$

Using Squeeze Theorem, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\bigg\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \bigg\rfloor=1.$$

Comment: I think you have a “$-1$” too much at the very right of the second and third line.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x \to 0}(x(\frac{1}{x}$-{$\frac{1}{x}$}))
$$  $$
$\lim_{x \to 0}$(1-x{$\frac{1}{x}$})=1-0=1
$$  $$
Where {  x }  is fractional part of x.